# Can I install Debian Unstable Scala 2.8.1 package in Ubuntu? Won't it cause problems?

Tags: installation, 10.10, apt, dpkg, debian

I am coding Scala and would like an up-to-date 2.8.1 of it to be installed in my Ubuntu 10.10 system, but there is only obsolete 2.7 package available in Ubuntu repositories, so I have to go Slackware-way and use manual installation from tarballs. At the same time there is already scala_2.8.1.dfsg-1_all.deb available for Debian. Can't I just install it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jar installer as follows:

First download the IzPack Installer from the Scala Website, http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads.

Run it with

sudo java -jar installer.jar

and use the default folder /usr/local/scala for the installation

(where for me it was sudo java -jar scala-2.8.1.final-installer.jar).

Then edit /etc/environment so PATH is as follows
PATH="... :/usr/local/scala/bin"
and add
SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/scala

Now logout and login again.

Comment: I know I can do this, but I want the package :-]

Answer (score 1):

Provided the dependencies are satisfiable, this *should* generally work.

Since this package probably has only been tested on Debian and not on Ubuntu there is a higher risk that e.g. it doesn't declare all the necessary dependencies or is incompatible with some change in Ubuntu.